# Sending input to application from Java?

Tags: java, windows, input

Platform is windows only.  From Java I'd like to send input (key strokes and mouse clicks) to the current running application (it's a full screen directx app if that matters).

I know theoretically I could use JNI/JNA to access the Win32 API and use or the like, but honestly not familiar with those nor the win32 api.  I'm hoping there is a nice easy Java library out there that has already wrapped this all up in a nice neat package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).

Comment: Good find, never knew about this.

Comment: PREFECT!  I tried to accept this answer by my browser is acting weird.